# React is not defined in working code

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This code is written by my classmate and when i check it on his web page it perfectly works. when i copy it to my pages all what i get are those mistakes

[image]

TodoList component (making list of items, what i gwt from input)

```
class TodoList extends React.Component{

// render this component
render() {
var items = this.props.items.map(function(item, index) {
  return (
    <li key={index}>
      <span>{item} </span> 
      <img className="delete" 
           src="delete.jpg" 
           onClick={this.props.removeItem.bind(this, index)} />
    </li> 
  );
}.bind(this));
return (
    <ul>{items}</ul>
)
}

}
```

TodoForm component (making hadleSubmit for form nad form itself)

```
class TodoForm extends React.Component{
// init component state
state = {
    item: ""
}
// add a new item -> call parent
handleSubmit = (e) => {
    // prevent normal submit event
    e.preventDefault();
    // call parent to add a new item
    this.props.onFormSubmit(this.state.item);
    // remove new typed item from text input
    e.target.children[0].value = "";
    // focus text input
    e.target.children[0].focus();

}

// item value is changed
onChange = (e) => {
  this.setState({item: e.target.value});
}

// render component
render(){
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <input type="text" onChange={this.onChange} />
        <input type="submit" value="Add" /> 
      </form>
    );
}

}
```

App component (writting adding, deleting of item)

```
class App extends React.Component {

// init component state
state = {
    items: []
}

// add a new item
addItem = (newItem) => {
    // returns a new list with a new item
  let newArr = this.state.items.concat(newItem);
    // render again
  this.setState({items: newArr});
}

// remove item
removeItem = (index) => {

    // remove from items array
    let newArr = this.state.items;
    newArr.splice(index, 1);
    // render again
    this.setState({items: newArr});
}

// render component
render(){
    return (
        <div>
            <TodoForm onFormSubmit={this.addItem} />
            <TodoList items={this.state.items} removeItem={this.removeItem} />
        </div>
    )
}

}

ReactDOM.render(
<App/>,
document.getElementById('root')
);
```

and html is (this was given by my teacher and he told that this shouldn't be changed)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Todo Example with React</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@latest/dist/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@latest/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/babel" src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Well, you can see in the log that the React file fails to load for whatever reason.

Comment: Hint: try to open this link [https://unpkg.com/react@16.0.0/dist/react.js](https://unpkg.com/react@16.0.0/dist/react.js)

Comment: So you can tell your teacher that the URLs to react are wrong.

Comment: thank you, that was it. i so relaxed because of teacher comment that checked everything exept those links.

Answer (score -1):

the links you are using are not accessing any part of react to provide you react environment and run your code. It's better for you if you create a react app using

```
npm install -g create-react-app
create-react-app app_name
npm start
```

Then add your react components into that app and run your app easily.

Comment: OR, he could simply fix the URL from which he's loading React.

Comment: But it will be easy for him to code if he will be using proper react environment to work. He will even be able to add other libraries to this. This is all about best practices which I follow.

Comment: Easier than fixing a typo?  okay.

Comment: Easier things are not always great and good practice if you are in hurry and just want to code to complete the assignment or something then remove the typo but if you really wanna learn environment setup, actual working, and adding new libraries then you should go with scratch thingy.